# How to authenticate with web services on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iap

I have a RESTful service running on GCP's App Engine which is secured by IAP. I'd like to invoke those methods from a web app but not sure how to set up authentication. The web app is written in TypeScript / Angular.
Any guidance/examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service account or ID token, after configuring your API to support authentication. You can find plenty of details and examples on the "Authentication Between Services" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication).